# Creating a simple black image with opencv using cvcreateimage

Tags: image, opencv

Very basic question coming from a newbie in OpenCV. I just want to create an image with every pixel set to `0` (black). I have used the following code in the main() function:

```
IplImage* imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 240), 8, 3);
```

And what I get is a solid gray image, instead of the black one.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please instead use the c++ api, `Mat img(240,320,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));`

Answer (score 20):

What version of opencv you are using?
For Mat,

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat image(320, 240, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: It should be vice-versa `Mat image(240, 320, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));`, since first argument is number of rows(width) and second is number of cols(height).

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest two more altrnatives:

```
    IplImage* imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 240), 8, 3);

    // Here you can set any color
    cvSet(imgScribble, cvScalar(0,0,0));


    // Here only black
    cvZero(imgScribble);
```

Comment: Thank You Very much!

Solution Working Flawlessly!!!

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

For Python:

```
import numpy as np
X_DIMENSION = 288
Y_DIMENSION = 382
black_image = np.zeros((X_DIMENSION, Y_DIMENSION))
```

With this code you generate a numpy array which is what is expected for opencv images and fill it with zero which is the color for black. This code is made for grayscale images. If you want it to be an RGB black image, just add `3` at the end of the tupple to create the dimensions `np.zeros((X_DIMENSION, Y_DIMENSION, 3))`

Comment: Shouldn't x and y switched since OpenCV `h, w, c = image.shape`?

Comment: For RGB it should be `black_image = np.zeros((Y_DIMENSION, X_DIMENSION, 3), dtype='uint8')`

Answer (score 1):

The call to

```
cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 240), 8, 3);
```

Create the image in the memory, but I don't think it initialize the data.

You should try this to initialize :

```
step= imgScribble->widthStep;
data = (uchar *)imgScribble->imageData;
for(i=0;i<imgScribble->height;i++) for(j=0;j<img->width;j++) for(k=0;k<3;k++) 
    data[i*step+j*3+k]=0;
```

(Inspired from [this (Example C Program)](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used solution posted by Andrey Smorodov.

Will try yours as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

black and white image mean single channel image. you can simply created it as follows.

```
Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC1, Scalar(a));
```

"a" in between 0-255

you can see more examlpe and details from following page
https://progtpoint.blogspot.com/2017/01/tutorial-3-create-image.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contribution:

```cpp
cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(320, 240), CV_8UC3);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#define LOAD_OPTION CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR 

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    IplImage  *image; 


    image = cvLoadImage("picture.jpg",0); // 0 : BLACK AND WHITE , Without 0 -> Color Picture
    cvNamedWindow("Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Image", image);
    waitKey(-1);

   return 0;
}
```