# c++ OpenCV - Create a cv::Mat rectangle with an alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv

I was hoping to simply use [Creating a simple black image with opencv using cvcreateimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984419/creating-a-simple-black-image-with-opencv-using-cvcreateimage) 's answer

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat image(320, 240, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

and modify it to

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat image(320, 240, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 255));
```

So that I could select the alpha value later if I wanted, but that isn't working for me.
How would I accomplish instantiating a cv::Mat with RGB and alpha?

Errors:

```
./canvas.cpp:31:27: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   31 |     Scalar backgroundRGBA(255,255,255,255); //of type cv::Scalar
```

```
./canvas.cpp:365:34: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘cv::Scalar vCanvas::backgroundRGBA(int)’
  365 |   Mat bg(width, height, CV_8UC4, backgroundRGBA); //Third argument is supposed to be an 8bit length 4 Scalar
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./main.cpp:15:
./canvas.cpp:31:12: note: declared here
   31 |     Scalar backgroundRGBA(255,255,255,255); //of type cv::Scalar
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not an OpenCV but C++ error. `backgroundRGBA` seems to already exist, try renaming it. Or try out `Scalar backgroundRGBA = Scalar::all(255);` if it does not work otherwise.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi cv::Scalar backgroundRGBA is stated only on line 31 as a class variable.  The function I am calling this in is a member of that class.  

I just did a sanity check ctrl-f and backgroundRGBA is only instantiated at line 31, as expected.

Comment: Well, the code that you originally posted works; so I can't reproduce the error: `cv::Mat image(320, 240, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 255));`. But it looks like your `backgroundRGBA` is a function and not a value.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Thank you for the assertion that this works.  I forgot that I can't initialize vectors such as ```vector<int> vectorName(4,0);``` in classes.  I must do ```Scalar backgroundRGBA = Scalar(255,255,255,255);```

Answer (score 1):

This was simply something I forgot about.  For some reason you can't initialize functions such as

```
vector<int> vectorName(4,0);
```

in a class constructor.

One must use the following (allegedly c++ 11+)

```
Scalar backgroundRGBA = Scalar(255,255,255,255);
```

As a side note, 255,255,255 is white, not black.  Whoops